# MVC4 razor Html.LabelFor for a Nullable<System.DateTime>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this property in my model :

```
[DisplayName("Birth Date")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> dtnasc { get; set; }
```

use on view the htmlhelper

```
 @Html.LabelFor(_ => _.dtnasc)
```

and receive this error : *Nullable object must have a value.*

When value of property *dtnasc* is null, **how can we get DisplayName Metadata**?

Comment: What does `@Html.Raw(Helpers.GetDisplayName<Models.ModelName>(_ => _.dtnasc));` do?

Comment: Obv replace ModelName with your model.

Comment: You must have something else wrong because the code you have shown works fine (displays _Birth Date_) and `@Html.LabelFor()` does not generate that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***"You must have something else wrong"***

The problem was on the next line, but the error always pointer to line @Html.LabelFor

*obvious i cant use ToString(...) in a null propertie*

```
@Html.LabelFor(_ => _.dtnasc)
<input type="text" id="dtnasc" name="dtnasc" value="@Model.dtnasc.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")" />
```

For my solution to this problem i did

on model add the DisplayFormat to format date:

```
[DisplayName("Birth Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> dtnasc { get; set; }
```

and on view i changed the tag input by Helper.EditorFor :

```
@Html.LabelFor(_ => _.dtnasc)
@Html.EditorFor(_ => _.dtnasc)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that model name is missing in your case in the view.

Make sure you have added following line in your view.

@model SolutionName.modelName